# CKEditor works - but get error "Uncaught ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I have an inline CKeditor on my page and it works fine. It posts AJAX after its been updated, all works great.

However, in the console I get the error **"Uncaught ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined"**

I discovered this when I was trying to modify the toolbar in the javascript, but the toolbar wasn't changing.

Any ideas what is going on here?

```
<div id="editor<?php echo $sub_category['id'] ?>" contenteditable="true" class="contentz ckeditor" typeID="<?php echo $sub_category['id'] ?>">
<?php if($sub_category['content']==""){ echo "Click here to add some content"; }else{ echo $sub_category['content']; } ?>
</div>
<script>

    // Turn off automatic editor creation first.
    CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
    CKEDITOR.inline('editor<?php echo $sub_category['id'] ?>');



</script>
```

This is called just before the body tag...

```
<script src="assets/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move

```
<script>
    CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
    CKEDITOR.inline('editor<?php echo $sub_category['id'] ?>');
</script>
```

after

```
<script src="assets/js/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
```

because you must load `ckeditor.js` library first and then configure it with `CKEDITOR` methods/properties